# what's the fs type for mounting an existing Ubuntu partition?

Tags: 11.10

Trying to repair the usual broken Ubuntu I try chrooting following directions from [this page](http://www.tuxation.com/chrooting-into-a-linux-environment.html) However when I arrive to the mounting step where I need to mount the existing Extended broken Linux partition I can't because don't know the type and there are many. I tried ext, ext2, ext3, ext4 ... none work. the type is also not optional if I leave it empty I get `mount: you must specify the filesystem type`

What is the type of choice to mount an existing Linux 11.10 partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you set this up using more-or-less defaults, you should use the command:

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda4 /mnt
```

Note the `-t ext4` part. Change `/mnt` to the mount point you decided upon.

Answer (score 1):

### [blkid](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/blkid.8.html)

All informations on attached drives and partitions needed for mounting can be read using the following command:

```
blkid
```

By this we will see the drive's device representation, its UUID and the file TYPE needed for mounting (or for entries in our fstab):

```
sudo mount -t TYPE /dev/sdXx /path/to/mountpoint
```